# Поиск нужной улицы

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios9

Необходимо подвязать API к приложению для поиска улицы по выбранному городу, (например выбираем Москву, сервер возвращает весь список улиц по Москве). Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно использовать Nominatim API от OpenStreetMap.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!